# Why does this Url RewriteRule not working for CSS & JavaScript files?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^tricks/([0-9]+) tricks.php?show=one&tid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tricks/([a-z]+) tricks.php?show=frmsec&sec=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tricks/?$ tricks.php?show=all [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^discussion/?$ discussion.php?show=all [NC,L]
```

this is not loading CSS and Javascript files

only 
http://localhost/web/tricks and http://localhost/discussion is working properly

Comment: What is the URL for the CSS and JS files?

Comment: <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/common.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/content.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/bjs_css.css'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='JS/bjs.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='JS/tricks.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='JS/dtqe.js'></script>

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (because I can't test it here), but you need something to exclude files. Here's an example (credits to .htacces from TYPO3):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]`

EdIt according to a comment from @bouke:

You have relative paths in your stylesheet linking. This won't work. When you're on localhost/web/tricks, the relative path is wrong (since you don't have a CSS folder in /web/tricks).

You need to either use absolute paths or use a base url tag (`<base ...>`)

Comment: @BhavikPatel use a `/` in front of the CSS path, to make it relative to the root, not the current path. Thus: `/CSS/common.css` (if it is at `http://localhost/CSS/common.css`).

Comment: still not chnages and my other page's css also not loading

Comment: set your baseurl `<base href="http://localhost/">` (or localhost/web/, where your root is). And then write your css href's like `href="stylesheets/base.css"` (according to your root). Watch out for the slashes. this browser-internally combines into `http://localhost/stylesheets/base.css`

Answer (score 0):

Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before `RewriteRule` .

Answer (score 0):

If you user the url `http://localhost/web/tricks/000` instead of `localhost/tricks.php?show=one&tid=000` your relative url's will be relative to `/web/tricks/` and no longer to `/`.

You either have to change the href to `../../CSS/content.css` or preferably use `/CSS/content.css`. The later will make the path relative to the root, not to the current page's 'directory'.